# How to upload a directory in .Net Core Web Api?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I saw some tutorials about file/files upload in .net core but I can't see tutorials for uploading directory. So, I want to upload all files and folders which are in the  selected folder.(the folder itself is also included.)

For example there is a directory tree like this(Directory `A` contains `file1.txt` and directory `B`. Directory `B` contains only `file2.txt`):

```
A
|   
-file1.txt
-B
 |
 -file2.txt
```

and I want to upload directory `A` to server directory `D\E\F`. So I choose the directory `A` in GUI. After the uploading , I want to see the directory `A` content in  `D\E\F\A` path.

In this below code, I can choose a folder in front end, but it only copy one file of the folder. What should I do?

I have a very basic `HTML(Angular)` like this:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input webkitdirectory directory type="file" #file placeholder="Choose file" (change)="uploadFile(file.files)" style="display:none;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="file.click()">Upload File</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="upload" *ngIf="progress > 0">
      {{progress}}%
    </span>
    <span class="upload" *ngIf="message">
      {{message}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`TypeScript(Angular)`:

```
      public uploadFile = (files) => {
        if (files.length === 0) {
          return;
        }

        let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

        this.httpClient.post(`http://192.168.1.10:58432/file`, formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
          .subscribe(event => {


 if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
          this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.message = 'Upload success.';
          this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
        }
      });
  }
```

`Server(.net core)` side:

```
[HttpPost("file")]
public async Task UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"\\UBUNTU-N55SL\\cloudStorage", file.FileName);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directories are different from files in that they're not data as such, but a logical structuring of storage. As directories are handled in different ways depending on the operating system of the server, they won't be included in a file upload operation. You could look at using FTP but for the purposes of your code you've posted, you will need to loop through the directories and files you want to upload, and place them in the desired target directories using your code logic.

Comment: how do I loop the directory structure in server side ?

Comment: The looping would need to be client-side, and would perform an individual upload of each file. The server would not do anything different.

Comment: But what should I do when I come across with an inner directory while looping?

Comment: That will be down to the user. For security reasons, a web client can't just go through the user's files accessing whatever it wants. So the looping would need to be at the UI, to keep prompting the user to select the next file. Not a particularly great UX! That's why you didn't find examples of directory upload. This is true of web apps generally, not anything about WebApi, .Net Core or Angular. So... you may wish to look into other approaches, such as getting the user to zip up the folder first so it's a single file upload, or perhaps moving away from a web page and using an FTP derivative.